# Github pages - Disable custom domain redirection for all but a single site?

Tags: github, github-pages, cname

I've been using `github pages` since a long time and use the custom domain redirection feature to redirect my [user website](https://github.com/prahladyeri/prahladyeri.github.io) from `prahladyeri.github.io` to my own domain which is <s>https://www.prahladyeri.com</s> by adding a `CNAME` file.

However, for the web-pages (`gh-pages` branch) of open source projects that I maintain, it automatically redirects a `foo` project to <s>`www.prahladyeri.com/foo`</s> when no `CNAME` is specified. Is it possible to use the default `prahladyeri.github.io/foo` scheme for my projects, but keep custom redirection on for my main site?

Is that something easily achievable?

**Update on 2022-11-14**

As of today, I've switched to the proper sub-domain https://prahladyeri.github.io. The old site will soon expire, I'm keeping this post only for academic interest.

Comment: Maybe the better solution is to separate open-source projects by putting them under a new account.

Comment: @DavidJacquel With multiple accounts for each project, you lose the integration advantage that Github provides (like gouping of all issues by status, single view for all pull-requests, etc.). These are some of the very advantages that I'm using Github in the first place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Jul 2016, I don't think this is possible. (https://help.github.com/articles/custom-domain-redirects-for-github-pages-sites/)

The Github Pages help article states that

```
Project Pages site owned by a user account, such as username.github.io/projectname, will be Automatically redirected to a subdirectory of a User Pages site custom domain (user.example.com/projectname), unless a different CNMAE is specified, such as project.example.com
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I deploy my site on GitHub pages and then just try to custom my domain which doesn't exit. But then when I open my website it will redirect to that custom domain. How would I delete that one. Help me what to do ?