# Use Github pages on multiple repositories when one has a custom CNAME already?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a Github repository set up to host a small static site. The repository that hosts this is in the following format:

```
username.github.io
```

This repository is setup to use a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) and has a CNAME file to do so properly. This repository works exactly as expected.

Now I want to set up a [project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) and utilize the `gh-pages` branch for a different repository. When I do this, though, the CNAME in the first repository seems to apply and I am redirected to `example.com/REPOSITORYNAME` instead of using the expected `username.github.io/projectname` associated with this separate repository.

---

How can I continue to use the `username.github.io` repository with a custom domain *and* the `gh-pages` branch on a different repository without redirecting the `gh-pages` repository to the custom domain defined in the first repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github pages - Disable custom domain redirection for all but a single site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714796/github-pages-disable-custom-domain-redirection-for-all-but-a-single-site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Aug 2016, I don't think this is possible. (https://help.github.com/articles/custom-domain-redirects-for-github-pages-sites/)

The Github Pages help article states that

```
Project Pages site owned by a user account, such as username.github.io/projectname, will be Automatically redirected to a subdirectory of a User Pages site custom domain (user.example.com/projectname), unless a different CNMAE is specified, such as project.example.com
```

See [Github pages - Disable custom domain redirection for all but a single site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714796/github-pages-disable-custom-domain-redirection-for-all-but-a-single-site)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a Github Organisation for each website you decide to manage this way.

In this case, I had to publish to `master` instead of `gh-pages`.

More informations here : https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/